# Using Windows 10 Multi-Touch Functionality In Gamemaker: Studio

Tags: game-maker, touch, multitouch

I have a multi-touch monitor that I am using in Windows 10. I am getting visual feedback on the monitor itself that multiple touches are being recognised. However, within my Gamemaker game, I cannot seem to recognise any other touch than the very first one. From the documentation, it seems that I should be able to just use the `device_mouse` functions, using `0,1,2,3` and `4` to stand for the different 'mice' that each press represents. However, this does not seem to work at all, for example in the following code:

```
if device_mouse_check_button(0,mb_left) {
Number = 1
}

else if device_mouse_check_button(0,mb_left) and device_mouse_check_button(1,mb_left) {
Number = 2
}
```

Can anybody shed some light on this problem? I cannot work out why this doesn't seem to be working. It recognises the first 'mouse' press, but as soon as I add the second finger it stops working.

Comment: You mean that with a single tap the mouse check 0 works, but as soon you use the multitouch feature, neither mouse checks for 0 or 1 works?

Comment: No, mouse check 0 works, but trying to run any code that relies on 0 and 1 being tapped doesn't work (because mouse 1 is not being detected at all). I've managed to get a response from YoYo last night, stating that multi-touch for non-mobile is not supported at the moment, but it is in the roadmap for Gamemaker 2.